# Domain name + nginx + tomcat settings

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx

I created a domain name and redefined it to your external IP address. Also start nginx and tomcat.
Redefined domain to an external IP address.

[truckpart4you.com:8081/spring](http://truckpart4you.com:8081/spring/)

I want to hide the port 8081 and the packet / spring /

For now I have some settings
**nginx.conf**

```
    server {
    listen 81;
    server_name  www.truckpart4you.com truckpart4you.com;

    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {

        proxy_pass  localhost:81/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }}
```

and **server.xml**(for tomcat)

```
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
```

How do I configure nginx and tomcat for vindovs?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
listen 81; # why 81 instead of 80???
server_name  www.truckpart4you.com truckpart4you.com;

access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {

    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8081;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

Your application should be deployed in root which is `http://localhost:8081/` instead of `http://localhost:8081/spring/.` You can easily do this with adding a section to server.xml file inside  tag.

```
<Context path="" docBase="<YOUR APP>" debug="0" reloadable="true">
```